# ISAAC cipher in python

Tags: python, encryption

Does anyone have any working implementations of the ISAAC cipher in python?

I tried to find this, but it seems no one ever did it.

Thanks.

Comment: It may help your question to link to or provide a description of the cipher.

Answer (score 4):

I read some code examples on the [ISAAC home page](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html) and the code appears straightforward to implement. If you need it in pure Python there are several examples in other languages to guide your porting effort.

Another way of using `isaac()` from Python is to build the C code as a shared library and access it via the [**ctypes module**, which is standard in 2.5+](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), but can be [found on PyPI for earlier versions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ctypes).  This should also perform much better than a direct port in pure Python.

Here's an example of building the C version of `isaac()` as a shared library and using it via ctypes. First you need to download `rand.c`, `rand.h`, and `standard.h` from the author's website, then build:

```
% gcc -shared -fPIC -o libisaac.so rand.c
```

Here is the Python code.  Note that the sizes of the fields in the `RandCtx` are dependent on whether the code is built for 32- or 64-bit platform. I tested on 64-bit Ubuntu. For 32-bit you'd need to change all of the fields to use `c_uint32`:

```
from ctypes import *

class RandCtx(Structure):
    RANDSIZL = 8
    RANDSIZ  = 1 << RANDSIZL
    _fields_ = [
        ('randcnt', c_uint64),
        ('randrsl', c_uint64 * RANDSIZ),
        ('randmem', c_uint64 * RANDSIZ),
        ('randa', c_uint64),
        ('randb', c_uint64),
        ('randc', c_uint64)
        ]

ctx = RandCtx()
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libisaac.so')
lib.randinit(byref(ctx), 0)
lib.isaac(byref(ctx))

for i in xrange(4):
    print ctx.randrsl[i]
```

Output:

```
% python isaac.py
14012348966175605106
8193820543905647488
4194352129441799609
12121047914186473054
```